# jQuery addClass not firing in production site

Tags: jquery, popup, addclass

Trying to change behavior of links (that are pulled in through an api) by adding a class. It works in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/webbrewers2/tjwdkzj2/ but not on the live WordPress site. The popup function works when the popup class is manually added to the link. I've changed relative position of the popup function but it hasn't helped.
Sample html:

```
<a class="wolfnet_listingLink" href="http://www.mlsfinder.com/ca_crrmls/davidnorwood/?action=listing_detail&amp;property_id=1045225">Click here</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.wolfnet_listingLink').addClass('popup');

$('.popup').click(function() {
 var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '','scrollbars=1,height=400,width=400');
 if (window.focus)
 {
   NWin.focus();
 }
 return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Have you opened the console to check for errors.

Comment: I should've mentioned that - yes, no errors.

Comment: Maybe it's dynamic? Have you tried `$(document).on('click', '.popup', function() {...`

Comment: Do you mean the link is dynamic? I'm not sure how I would format that. If I add the link to a page it still doesn't add the popup class.

Comment: And even if I don't try to addClass and put the click function on wolfnet_listingLink class, it still doesn't pop up.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I bound the popup function to the generated link class - didn't need addClass at all. And apparently WordPress was having an issue with using $ instead of jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.wolfnet_listingLink').click(function() {
 var NWin = window.open(jQuery(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=600,width=800');
 if (window.focus)
 {
   NWin.focus();
 }
 return false;
});
});
```